# Longest substring repeating atleast k times

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, memory-efficient

I am given a string of large length (say, 100,000) and an integer k, and I have to compute length of the largest sub-string which repeats in the given string atleast k times.
I found answers to this particular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090289/find-longest-repetitive-sequence-in-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311259/longest-repeated-k-times-substring), but I wanted to know if there is any other efficient method to solve this question other than suffix trees?

Comment: It's less efficient, but easier to understand than suffix trees: do a binary search over answer length, compute all polynomial hashes (https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html) of substrings of such length and see if there's a hash which has _>= k_ occurrences. Computing hashes of all substrings of a fixed length is _O(n)_, binary search has _log n_ iterations, so overall complexity is _O(n log n)_.

Comment: @Fas When doing binary search, how do you move left or right?

Comment: @vivek_23 depending on is there's a hash with _>= k_ occurrences or not. That works, because if there's a string `s` of with _k_ occurrences, `s[:-1]` also has at least _k_ occurrences.

Comment: @fas But how to decide to go left or right? It is quite possible that longer string has >= k occurrences?

Comment: @vivek_23 If we check strings of length _x_ and there's a hash with _>= k_ occurrences, we go left to check if there's a string with length _<= x_ with _>= k_ occurrences, otherwise go right. During binary search we just try to find a maximum number _x_, such as exists string `s` with _>= k_ occurrences and length _x_, sure then exists a string of length _x - 1_ (`s[:-1]` for example), _x - 2_ (`s[:-2]`), ..., 1 (just `s[0]` for example). Because binary search finds maximum, it's impossible that string with length _> x_ has _>= k_ occurrences.

Comment: @fas Not sure if I understand correctly, does `abcabcdefgdefgdefgdefg` for example with  k = 3, work with your approach? IMO, the answer for this should be `defg`.

Comment: @ShreyTripathi Do you have link to the problem?

Comment: Also, no response on your previous questions!

Comment: @vivek_23 no, not `defg` in this example, this approach doesn't disallow strings to be intersected, with given approach answer seems to be `defgdefg`. I don't think suffix trees can disallow strings not to be intersected too.

Comment: @fas `defgdefg` comes only twice but k is 3.

Comment: @vivek_23 `defgdefg` comes 3 times: `abcabc<1>defg<2>defg</1><3>defg</2>defg</3>`

Comment: @fas Ahh, yes they overlap also. Here, I start search between 1 and 22, mid is 11. No substring of length 11 seems to satisfy. So, we again go right?

Comment: @vivek_23 Left, search between 1 and 10, mid 5, `defgd` exists for example, right, search between 5 and 10, mid 7, `defgdef` exists for example, right, search between 7 and 10, mid 8, `defgdefg` exists, right, search between 8 and 10, mid 9, no such string exists, left, search between 8 and 8, so this is 8 :)

Comment: @vivek_23, I am really sorry for the late response! I was just studying about suffix trees and came across this problem, and wondered if there was another algorithm to solve this problem. I don't have any link to the problem :(

Comment: @fas Makes sense but I don't think collecting substrings of length say `m` is an O(1) operation.

Comment: @ShreyTripathi Ok, that's fine. I am pondering on previous questions you asked here on SO. Accept the solution that suits the best(it's ok if you don't accept mine, I just want you to respond)

Comment: @vivek_23 We don't collect substrings, we collect their polynomial hashes (what is it and how it works you can read here https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html) and this can be done in `O(n)` for all substrings of a fixed by binary search length `m`

Comment: @fas, I didn't quite understand your solution. I can perform binary search only if I know the length of the required substring. I don't know that(I have to find that out); or are you implying that I start taking lengths from 1, 2,....len(string) and create a separate hash table for each one of them? Really sorry for the late reply

Comment: @fas nice info, I will look into it.

Comment: @ShreyTripathi we're doing binary search to find maximum length (see example for string `abcabcdefgdefgdefgdefg` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235589/longest-substring-repeating-atleast-k-times?noredirect=1#comment108336869_61235589 and in other comments above), we're creating separate hash table during binary search for each `mid` value (which is length we're testing if it's possible to find `k` substrings of such length) in it

Comment: @vivek_23 I wrote a long answer to sum up our discussion, which I hope explains everything. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61261931/3365922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was large discussion in comments, I think it's better write an answer to sum up. TL;DR [Longest substring repeating atleast k times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235589/longest-substring-repeating-atleast-k-times#comment108331149_61235589)

There is less efficient method, but it's really easier to understand than suffix trees: all you need to know is polynomial hashing and binary search.

#### **1. String polynomial hash**

Read about it here https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html. Below is short description of this technique.

Let's say we have string `s`, integers `p` and `mod`. Now we can define hash function:

```
hash(s) = (ord(s[0])*p^(len(s)-1) + ord(s[1])*p^(len(s)-2) + ... + ord(s[len(s)-1])*p^0) % mod
```

where `ord` is a function returning an integer by character (let's say it's an ASCII-code of a character). Polynomial hash can be easily calculated for each prefix of string in *O(len(s))*:

```
# h[i] is a hash of prefix of length i.
# For example s = "abacaba",
# h[0] = hash("") = 0
# h[1] = hash("a")
# h[2] = hash("ab")
# ...
# h[7] = hash("abacaba")

h[0] = 0
for i in 1..n:
    h[i] = (h[i-1] * p + ord(s[i-1])) % mod
```

Also let's precalculate *p^0 % mod, p^1 % mod, ..., p^len(s) % mod* in array `pow`:

```
# pow[i] is (p^i) % mod
pow[0] = 1
for i in 1..n:
    pow[i] = (pow[i-1] * p) % mod
```

Using arrays `h` and `pow` we can easily calculate hash of any substring of the string `s`:

```
# get_substring_hash returns hash(s[l] + s[l+1] + ... + s[r-1]).
def get_substring_hash(s, l, r):
    value = h[r] - h[l]*pow[r-l]    # line a
    return (value%mod + mod) % mod  # line b
```

Let's understand why code above works.

```
h[r] = (ord(s[r-1])*p^0 + ord(s[r-2])*p^1 + ... + ord(s[l-1])*p^(r-l) + ord(s[l-2])*p^(r-l+1) + ...) % mod
h[l] = (                                          ord(s[l-1])*p^0     + ord(s[l-2])*p^1       + ...) % mod
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As you can see we need only `^^^`-part from `h[r]` so we have to get rid of `~~~`-part. `~~~`-part in `h[r]` `p^(r-l)` times larger than in `h[l]` and this explains *line a*.

*Line b* is kinda magic when operating with `% mod`, `value` after *line a* can be negative, so `value%mod + mod` definitely makes is positive. At the same time if `value` was positive after *line a* `value%mod + mod` is larger than `mod`, so `(value%mod + mod) % mod` will definitely return value in range *0, 1, ..., mod-1*.

Finally, `mod` is a large prime number like *10^9+7* and `value` is a small number, but larger than any possible ASCII-code like *239* (read in article why so).

Some notes:

- Hashes may collide, because we have only `mod` possible values of hash but number of strings is infinite. How to deal with it read in article.
- Doing operations like `h[r] - h[l]*pow[r-l]` may require using of 64-bit types of integers.

#### **2. Binary search**

Just read about it on Wikipedia, there's nothing specific https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm.

#### **3. Longest substring repeating at least k times solution**

Let's say we precalculated arrays `h` and `pow`. Let's do binary search to find maximum length `ans` of string such that there are `k` or more such substrings in the given string `s`.

Why binary search works here? Because if there's some length `x` such as there are `k` or more equal substrings in `s` of length `x`, then there's definitely `k` or more equal substrings in `s` of length `x-1` (just remove last letter from our matches).

How will binary search work? Let's say we're currently testing if there are `k` or more equal substrings of length `mid`. We're going to calculate all hashes of length `mid` (using `get_substring_hash`) and we'll make a decision of changing borders of binary search if there is a `k` equal hashes or not.

For example: *s = "abcabcdefgdefgdefgdefg", k = 3*. Answer is *"defgdefg"*:

```
abcabcdefgdefgdefgdefg
      ^^^^^^^^          occurence 1
          ^^^^^^^^      occurence 2
              ^^^^^^^^  occurence 3
```

Binary search iterations:

```
l =  1, r = 22, mid = 11. No substring of length 11 satisfy.
l =  1, r = 10, mid =  5. There should be hash("defgd")    be seen 3 times.
l =  5, r = 10, mid =  7. There should be hash("defgdef")  be seen 3 times.
l =  7, r = 10, mid =  8. There should be hash("defgdefg") be seen 3 times.
l =  8, r = 10, mid =  9. No substring of length 9  satisfy.
l =  8, r =  8.           That means answer is 8.
```

As you can see, complexity is *O(n log n)*: *round(log n)* binary search iterations and *O(n)* complexity per iteration if you use something like `std::unordered_map` to check if there's a hash with *>= k* occurrences or not.

I really hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understood the algorithm. Just one thing, what is 'p' here? It can be any number, right?

Comment: It definitely can be a prime number larger than any number your function `ord` returns (larger than any ASCII-code). I'm not able to say for sure that `p` can be not a prime, seems it would work too