# Longest common substring in string itself

Tags: c, string, algorithm, lcs

Given a string like `"geekthegeertheregeers"` .So we have to find longest common substring in the string itself.

Like in this case `"geer"` will be longest common substring. 
My question is that which algorithm will be applied here.can LCS be modified to find this solution of this problem?

Comment: What are you looking for? The longest substring that appears twice? The longest substring a string has in common with itself is itself, so you don't seem to be looking for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find longest repetitive sequence in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090289/find-longest-repetitive-sequence-in-a-string)

Comment: I was asked this in amazon interview.So it will be longest substring which should appear many times. so `max(all substrings) && max(length(all substrings))`

Comment: @templatetypedef I have to admit, your linked answer is one of the more informative non-code answers I've seen on SO. Thanks for that.

Comment: "egeer" appears twice... why is "geer" the longest common substring?

Comment: Check this link [**Analysis of Longest common substring matching**](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/10/analysis-of-longest-common-substring_18.html)

Answer (score 2):

Is the question "finding longest substring occur more than once in substring set"?
Result for "geekthegeertheregeers" should be "egeer"?

If so, you can build suffix array for input string, and construct LCP(Longest Common Prefix) array for suffix array. Both can be done in O(N) (N is length of input string).

Reference:

1. Suffix Array (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array )
2. LCP array (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array )