# Shortening a string

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
a = babababbaaaaababbbab
```

And it needs to be shortened so it looks like this:

```
(ba)3(b)2(a)5ba(b)3ab
```

So basically it needs to take all repeating characters and write how many times they are repeating instead of printing them.
I managed to do half of this:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = 'babababbaaaaababbbab'
grouped = ["".join(grp) for patt,grp in groupby(a)]
solved = [str(len(i)) + i[0] for i in grouped if len(i) >= 2]
```

but this only does this for characters that are repeating but not patterns. I get it that I could do this by finding 'ab' pattern in string but this needs to be viable for every possible string. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090289/find-longest-repetitive-sequence-in-a-string

Comment: This is ambiguous.  What is the expected output for `aaabbbaaabbb`?  Is it `(a)3(b)3(a)3(b)3` or `(aaabbb)2`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach it's a(3)b(3).

Comment: @Nenad Why?  How is the algorithm going to know?

Comment: I agree with @SvenMarnach, you would need to define your problem constraints in detail.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, longest match? I think that would save the most space.

Comment: @Haris I'm not sure this is about saving space.  `(b)3` is longer than `bbb` after all, but it seems the substitution is desired anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I don't think substitution is desired. The question says, shortening is desired. I guess while looking for patterns one can compare which one would be efficient and would shorten the string the most.

Comment: @Haris I've taken this pattern from the example input and output.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, Hmm. That does make the question ambiguous.

Comment: Why does `bababab` become `b(ab)3` and not `(ba)3b`?

Comment: this might be a good question for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: how about start to find pattern of length 1 and then 2 and then 3...
so you'll get
len:1  'babababbaaaaababbbab' =>  'bababab2a5bab3ab'
len:2 'bababab2a5bab3ab' => (ba)3b2a5bab3ab
len:3 '(ba)3b2a5bab3ab' => (ba)3b2a5bab3ab
till ... len: half of input

Comment: Your "shortened" string is actually one character longer than your original string...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> repl= lambda match:'({}){}'.format(match.group(1), len(match.group())//len(match.group(1)))
>>> re.sub(r'(.+?)\1+', repl, 'babababbaaaaababbbab')
'(ba)3(b)2(a)5ba(b)3ab'
```

Not much to explain here. The pattern `(.+?)\1+` matches repeating character sequences, and the lambda function rewrites them to the form `(sequence)number`.

Comment: Awesome ! I think i might spare a good time to master regex. Really good answer.

Comment: For `aabaabaab`, this gives a rather unintuitive `(a)2(baa)2b` instead of `(aab)3`. Although that's not to say it's wrong - the problem is a bit under-specified.

Comment: @Dukeling That's to conform with OP's statement that `aaabbbaaabbb` is to become `(a)3(b)3(a)3(b)3` - it repeats the shortest possible sequence. If that's undesirable, you can try changing `(.+?)\1+` to `(.+)\1+`, though that also has some weird quirks - for example it'll turn `abababab` into `(abab)2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, the code is a mess, but I just wanted to have a quick fun, so I let it be like this

```
a = 'babababbaaaaababbbab'

def compress(text):
    for i in range(1, len(text) // 2):
        for j, c in enumerate(text[:-i if i > 0 else len(text)]):
            pattern = text[j:i+j]
            new_text = pattern_repeats_processor(pattern, text, j)
            if new_text != text:
                return compress(new_text)
    return text

def pattern_repeats_processor(pattern, text, i):
    chunk = pattern
    count = 1 
    while chunk == pattern and i + (count + 1) * len(pattern) < len(text):
        chunk = text[i + count * len(pattern): i + (count + 1) * len(pattern)] 
        if chunk == pattern:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            break
    if count > 1:
        return text[:i] + '(' + pattern + ')' + str(count) + text[i + (count + 0) * len(pattern):]
    return text

print(compress(a))
print(a)
```

It makes 
babababbaaaaababbbab =>
(ba)3(b)2(a)5ba(b)3ab

P.S. Of course answer of Rowing is miles better, pretty impressive even

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for but here hope this helps.

```
A=a.count('a')
B=a.count('b')
AB=a.count('ab')
BAB=a.count('bab')
BA=a.count('ba')
print(A,'(a)',B,'(b)',AB,'(ab)',BAB,'(bab)',BA,'(ba)')
```

Comment: This doesn't even seem to give the correct output for the example in the question, never mind the more general problem.