# Algorithm to find the most repetitive (not the most common) sequence in a string (aka tandem repeats)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm (possibly implemented in Python) able to find the most REPETITIVE sequence in a string. Where for REPETITIVE, I mean any combination of chars that is repeated over and over without interruption (tandem repeat).

The algorithm I am looking for **is not** the same as the **"find the most common word"** one. In fact, the repetitive block doesn't need to be the most common word (substring) in the string.

For example:

```
s = 'asdfewfUBAUBAUBAUBAUBAasdkBAjnfBAenBAcs'
> f(s)
'UBAUBAUBAUBAUBA' #the "most common word" algo would return 'BA'
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to tackle this. Any help is very welcome.

---

**UPDATE**

A little extra example to clarify that I want to be returned the sequence with the most number of repetition, whatever its basic building block is.

```
g = 'some noisy spacer'
s = g + 'AB'*5 + g + '_ABCDEF'*2 + g + 'AB'*3
> f(s)
'ABABABABAB' #the one with the most repetitions, not the max len
```

Examples from @rici:

```
s = 'aaabcabc'
> f(s)
'abcabc'

s = 'ababcababc'
> f(s)
'ababcababc' #'abab' would also be a solution here
             # since it is repeated 2 times in a row as 'ababcababc'.
             # The proper algorithm would return both solutions.
```

Comment: By repetitive, do you mean a sub-string that occurs at least twice?

Comment: Take a look at suffix trees and Ukkonen's algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find longest repetitive sequence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090289/find-longest-repetitive-sequence-in-a-string)

Comment: Longest in repetitions or longest in length?

Comment: @Oliver Longest repetition.

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes, at least twice in a row. The more the better.

Comment: @wwii I can't figure out the implementation of that algo.

Comment: @wwii Even if the similarity in the title may mislead, with this question I am asking a completely different algo. It is not about finding the most repeated sequence in a string, but the most REPETITIVE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution based on `((\w+?)\2+)` regex but with additional improvements:

```
import re
from itertools import chain


def repetitive(sequence, rep_min_len=1):
    """Find the most repetitive sequence in a string.

    :param str sequence: string for search
    :param int rep_min_len: minimal length of repetitive substring
    :return the most repetitive substring or None
    """
    greedy, non_greedy = re.compile(r'((\w+)\2+)'), re.compile(r'((\w+?)\2+)')

    all_rep_seach = lambda regex: \
        (regex.search(sequence[shift:]) for shift in range(len(sequence)))

    searched = list(
        res.groups()
        for res in chain(all_rep_seach(greedy), all_rep_seach(non_greedy))
        if res)

    if not sequence:
        return None

    cmp_key = lambda res: res[0].count(res[1]) if len(res[1]) >= rep_min_len else 0
    return max(searched, key=cmp_key)[0]
```

You can test it like so:

```
def check(seq, expected, rep_min_len=1):
    result = repetitive(seq, rep_min_len)
    print('%s => %s' % (seq, result))
    assert result == expected, expected


check('asdfewfUBAUBAUBAUBAUBAasdkBAjnfBAenBAcs', 'UBAUBAUBAUBAUBA')
check('some noisy spacerABABABABABsome noisy spacer_ABCDEF_ABCDEFsome noisy spacerABABAB', 'ABABABABAB')
check('aaabcabc', 'aaa')
check('aaabcabc', 'abcabc', rep_min_len=2)
check('ababcababc', 'ababcababc')
check('ababcababcababc', 'ababcababcababc')
```

Key features:

1. used greedy `((\w+)\2+)` and non-greedy `((\w+)\2+?)` regex;
2. search repetitive substring in all substrings with the shift from the beginning (e.g.'string' => ['string', 'tring', 'ring', 'ing', 'ng', 'g']);
3. selection is based on the number of repetitions not on the length of subsequence (e.g. for 'ABABABAB_ABCDEF_ABCDEF' result will be 'ABABABAB', not '_ABCDEF_ABCDEF');
4. the minimum length of a repeating sequence is matters (see 'aaabcabc' check).

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your solution, however, with any input, the `result` is always None.

Answer (score 13):

With combination of `re.findall()` (using specific *regex* patten) and `max()` functions:

```
import re

#  extended sample string
s = 'asdfewfUBAUBAUBAUBAUBAasdkjnfencsADADADAD sometext'

def find_longest_rep(s):
    result = max(re.findall(r'((\w+?)\2+)', s), key=lambda t: len(t[0]))
    return result[0]

print(find_longest_rep(s))
```

The output:

```
UBAUBAUBAUBAUBA
```

---

The crucial pattern:

- `((\w+?)\2+)`:

  - `(....)` - the outermost captured group which is the 1st captured group
  - `(\w+?)` - any non-whitespace character sequence enclosed into the 2nd captured group; `+?` - quantifier, matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
  - `\2+` - matches the same text as most recently matched by the 2nd capturing group

Comment: Could you please share the expected time complexity of the program?

Comment: Wonderful solution! Thanks. I will test it with some examples before accepting the answer.

Comment: Here are two examples of strings which fail: `longest_rep('aaabcabc') =>  'aaa'` (should be `'abcabc'`); `longest_rep('ababcababc') => 'abab'` (should be `'ababcababc'`)

Comment: @rici You are right, I have added a more meaningful example to my post. However, this solution is still very helpful `re.findall(r'((\w+?)\2+)', s)` finds all the repeated blocks, getting the one with more repetition is then a piece of cake.

Comment: If nothing better pops up today, I feel this answer deserves to be accepted since it gave me a very useful suggestion on how to proceed with the implementation of the algorithm I am looking for.

Comment: @alec_djinn: my point was that regex does *not* find all repeated blocks under certain circumstances. For example, on input `'aabcabcabc'`, which includes the thrice-repeated 'abcabcabc', findall returns `[('aa', 'a'), ('bcabca', 'bca')]`. Similarly, on `'ababcababcababc'`, which is three repetitions of `ababc`, it returns only blocks repeated twice: `[('abab', 'ab'), ('cababcabab', 'cabab')]`.

Comment: @rici Thanks for your insight! Tha is indeed a problem. I have added your examples in the post. Do you have any solution to offer?

Comment: @alec_djinn: I don't have a solution offhand, other than the obvious O(n^2) solution of looking at every substring. (That can be made more efficient by terminating the endpoint scan early; in practice it is probably fast enough unless your strings are very long.) But I suspect that an O(n) solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

What you are searching for is an algorithm to find the 'largest' primitive tandem repeat in a string. Here is a paper describing a linear time algorithm to find all tandem repeats in a string and by extension all primitive tandem repeats. [Gusfield. Linear Time Algorithms for Finding and Representing all Tandem Repeats in a String](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/lineartime.pdf)

Comment: Do you know where can I find an implementation of it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute force algorithm that I wrote. Maybe it will be useful:

```
def find_most_repetitive_substring(string):
max_counter = 1
position, substring_length, times = 0, 0, 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(len(string) - i):
        counter = 1
        if j == 0:
            continue
        while True:
            if string[i + counter * j: i + (counter + 1) * j] != string[i: i + j] or i + (counter + 1) * j > len(string):
                if counter > max_counter:
                    max_counter = counter
                    position, substring_length, times = i, j, counter
                break
            else:
                counter += 1
return string[position: position + substring_length * times]
```